# Multivariate meta-analysis without individual patient data

Tags: meta-analysis

Here is what I have. I have the results of 20 studies ($i=1,\dots,20$). For each study $i$, I have 6 outcomes $y_{ij}$ ($j=1,\dots,6$) and the within-variance of outcome $j$ in study $i$ $\sigma_{ij}^2$. I don't have any individuals participant data (IPD). As the variability across study is quite high (due to different baseline characteristics of patients across studies), I opted for a random effect model and I assume the following:
$$y_{ij}\sim N(\theta_{ij},\sigma_{ij}^2)$$
$$\theta_{ij}\sim N(\theta_j,\tau_j)$$
Basically, the first approach would be to run 6 meta-analysis independantly for the 6 outcomes. However, I observed that the weights are the same across studies (as the variances are more or less the same). What I would like is a model that put less weight to studies that cleary overestimate or underestimate the outcome. Ideally, I'm looking for a multivariate model, as the studies that underestimate or overestimate one outcome, also do it for the other outcomes (which due to different baseline characteristic). I imagine it could be solved by assuming a $\tau$ that is shared across outcomes. Something like a hierarchical model with partial pooling. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot suggest you anything regarding tau... but you could try adding a meaningful moderator and perform meta-regression with mvmeta

Comment: On what basis are you deciding that some studies "clearly overestimate or underestimate the outcome"? Deciding that you want to give a study less weight because you don't like its results seems risky.